# Rosbag and simulated time

Tags: ros, rosbag, syncronization, timer, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am trying to run a bag file if simulated time but I am not succeeding on it. Here is what happens:
After I run the bag file with the command

```
rosbag play --clock -l laser_scanner3.bag
```

I am checking the timestamp published  by the topic **\clock**, i.e. the simulated time, and the timestamp presented in another topic, which is not the same as the one from the \clock topic. I need to solve this dyssynchrony, because, otherwise, I will not be able to use the transformations from **TF**.

I know that this file were originally recorded with ORCA and after transformed in **.bag** format. Maybe, the issue is here.

Any guess on how I can solve this issue?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244011/rosbag-and-simulated-time/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was related with a lack of sync between the several timetamps from the proper bagfile. The solution is well documented [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook)!!!

---

Originally posted by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) with karma: 236 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0